# Replace sub-query result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, coalesce

I need if sub query result is null then it will replace with '-'. I tried this

`REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )`

`REPLACE((SELECT [StandNo] FROM [dbo].[BusStand] where id=b.[ReturnStand]), char(0), '-')`

But with no solution because i think it is taking subquery as string_expression.

Solution below `(SELECT isnull([StandNo],'-') FROM [dbo].[BusStand] where id=b.[ReturnStand])` also didn't work.

Sorry guys i found problem is not with subquery `b.[ReturnStand]` is null because of that it select zero rows and place null in result. My query is something like this.

```
SELECT b.[Id],
       b.[Date],
       (SELECT [BusId]
        FROM   [dbo].[Bus]
        WHERE  id = [breakDownBusNo])           AS Bus,
       (SELECT [RouteNo]
        FROM   [dbo].[Route]
        WHERE  id = bl.[routeNo])               AS [Route No],
       (SELECT [StandName]
        FROM   [dbo].[BusStand]
        WHERE  id = b.[stand])                  AS [Breakdown Stand],
       b.[DeadKm]                               AS [Distance From Depo],
       (SELECT COALESCE([StandNo], 0)
        FROM   [dbo].[BusStand]
        WHERE  id = b.[ReturnStand])            [On Route Stand],
       COALESCE([ReturnKm], 0)                  AS [Distance of on route place],
       ( b.[DeadKm] + COALESCE([ReturnKm], 0) ) AS Total
FROM   [dbo].[BreakDown] AS b
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Bus Log] AS bl
               ON b.BusLogId = bl.Id
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[DriverAttendance] AS da
               ON da.Id = b.DrvrAttnDnceIdLog
```

Please don't go in query complexity i just need to show where i am using it. Now how can i replace null with '-' in on route stand.

Comment: can you share it on sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use [**COALESCE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.105).aspx) function

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT [StandNo] FROM [dbo].[BusStand] where id=b.[ReturnStand]) , '-')
FROM [dbo].[tableA] AS b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong Your Need to Add Column Name or Variables in `string_expression`

```
SELECT REPLACE(isnull([StandNo],0),'0', '-') FROM [dbo].[BusStand] 
where id=b.[ReturnStand]
```

or Better Ways

No need to Use `Replace`

```
....IN
( SELECT isnull([StandNo],'-') FROM [dbo].[BusStand] 
where id=b.[ReturnStand] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
(SELECT ISNULL([StandNo] ,  '-') FROM [dbo].[BusStand] where id=b.[ReturnStand])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly do this

```
SELECT b.[Id],
       b.[Date],
       (SELECT [BusId]
        FROM   [dbo].[Bus]
        WHERE  id = [breakDownBusNo])           AS Bus,
       (SELECT [RouteNo]
        FROM   [dbo].[Route]
        WHERE  id = bl.[routeNo])               AS [Route No],
       (SELECT [StandName]
        FROM   [dbo].[BusStand]
        WHERE  id = b.[stand])                  AS [Breakdown Stand],
       b.[DeadKm]                               AS [Distance From Depo],

   **** (SELECT isnull([StandNo], '-')
    FROM   [dbo].[BusStand]
    WHERE  id = b.[ReturnStand])            [On Route Stand], ****


    COALESCE([ReturnKm], 0)                  AS [Distance of on route place],
   ( b.[DeadKm] + COALESCE([ReturnKm], 0) ) AS Total
    FROM   [dbo].[BreakDown] AS b
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Bus Log] AS bl
           ON b.BusLogId = bl.Id
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[DriverAttendance] AS da
           ON da.Id = b.DrvrAttnDnceIdLog
```